# Mysql - Select nid from the table based on latest date using Joins

Tags: mysql

Tables - Table1

Table1
 
- Contains fields - (nid,date,profileid)
- contains data (1,2012-12-1,12),(2,2013-5-12,12),(3,2012-10-10,13),(4,2013-1-20,13)

Expected output - select nid based on latest date for every profileid

I am not able to select the nid from the table based on latest date Group by profileid

Comment: Care to add the expected output explicitly for given example?

Comment: Expected output: 12 2, 13 4

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want something like this:

```
select 
   nid, 
   profileid 
from Table1 
group by profileid 
having max(`date`)
```

A slightly more accurate way would be to use a derived table to get your max dates and join back to your desired table:

```
select 
   Table1.nid, 
   Table1.profileid 
from Table1
 inner join (select profileid, 
             max(date) as maxdate 
             from Table1
             group by profileid) derived on Table1.date = derived.maxdate
                                  and Table1.profileid = derived.profileid
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f62b/12/0)

Comment: I have tried this query but its no giving me the latest date my latest date for article is 2013 but this query is giving me result by 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?
Select nid, max(date) from table1 group by profileid

Comment: Yes, But from above query i am getting the latest date but not the right nid